# Mysql Grouping of Max field by month on a set of Fields

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I would like to generate a SQL to list to display the maximum tally count based on enumerated group of values on a monthly basis. As this would be useful for analytics based algorithm in displaying the total impressions of a particular data type.

Please check my sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company_attendance_tally` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `sick_type` enum('VACATION','SICK','MATERNITY') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `leave_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `start_date` (`start_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=32 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `company_attendance_tally`
--

INSERT INTO `company_attendance_tally` (`id`, `start_date`, `sick_type`, `leave_count`) VALUES
(1, '2013-03-01 16:58:44', 'VACATION', 5),
(2, '2013-03-15 10:44:35', 'SICK', 43),
(3, '2013-03-21 17:03:33', 'MATERNITY', 44),
(4, '2013-03-07 23:01:30', 'MATERNITY', 10),
(5, '2013-03-22 17:07:07', 'MATERNITY', 1),
(6, '2013-03-08 19:33:04', 'VACATION', 40),
(7, '2013-03-17 12:27:00', 'MATERNITY', 15),
(8, '2013-03-03 23:26:48', 'SICK', 11),
(9, '2013-03-05 02:16:37', 'MATERNITY', 41),
(10, '2013-03-20 12:04:28', 'MATERNITY', 18),
(11, '2013-03-18 02:10:00', 'MATERNITY', 1),
(12, '2013-03-03 09:47:02', 'MATERNITY', 19),
(13, '2013-03-22 10:17:52', 'MATERNITY', 25),
(14, '2013-03-03 19:41:52', 'VACATION', 10),
(15, '2013-03-02 19:28:41', 'SICK', 39),
(16, '2013-03-01 20:45:26', 'SICK', 42),
(17, '2013-03-26 23:52:16', 'MATERNITY', 29),
(18, '2013-03-29 14:10:58', 'SICK', 44),
(19, '2013-03-27 03:11:40', 'MATERNITY', 12),
(20, '2013-03-06 18:38:28', 'MATERNITY', 30),
(21, '2013-03-07 20:49:14', 'VACATION', 27),
(22, '2013-03-13 11:38:45', 'VACATION', 14),
(23, '2013-03-02 19:13:31', 'SICK', 2),
(24, '2013-03-01 10:08:18', 'SICK', 27),
(25, '2013-03-20 01:56:38', 'VACATION', 3),
(26, '2013-03-04 21:02:05', 'SICK', 7),
(27, '2013-03-17 00:47:17', 'MATERNITY', 36),
(28, '2013-03-04 08:12:56', 'VACATION', 5),
(29, '2013-03-18 08:50:57', 'SICK', 34),
(30, '2013-03-26 02:20:58', 'VACATION', 20),
(31, '2013-03-27 10:27:00', 'SICK', 21);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbd1e3

I would like to display a similar output below based on the above scenario:

```
month|  day       |  sick_type  |      leave_count |
-----------------------------------------------------
    3|    08      |   VACATION  | 40  
    3|    29      |   SICK      | 29
    3|    21      |   MATERNITY |  44
and so on so forth...
    4|    ...     |   MATERNITY |  ..
    4|    ...     |   SICK      |  ..
    4|    ...     |   VACATION  |  ..
    5|    ...     |   MATERNITY |  ..
    5|    ...     |   SICK      |  ..
    5|    ...     |   VACATION  |  ..
```

Comment: So all you want to do is split the date into two columns, month and day?

Comment: I don't understand how the data set relates to the result set... 29/29 Where does that come from?

Comment: My mistake it should be 29-44 as it should get the largest/greatest amount in the subset. :) pls see the correct output from @peterm below. tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want you can do following *by leveraging non-standard MySQL `GROUP BY extension`*

```
SELECT MONTH(start_date) month, 
       DAYOFMONTH(start_date) day,
       sick_type,
       leave_count
  FROM 
(
  SELECT start_date, sick_type, leave_count
    FROM company_attendance_tally
   WHERE start_date >= '2013-01-01'
     AND start_date <  '2014-01-01'
   ORDER BY MONTH(start_date), sick_type, leave_count DESC
) q
 GROUP BY MONTH(start_date), sick_type
```

**Note:** Month values alone (without a year values) in the resultset make sense only if you limit the resultset by one year boundaries (see `WHERE` clause).

Output:

```
| MONTH | DAY | SICK_TYPE | LEAVE_COUNT |
|-------|-----|-----------|-------------|
|     3 |   8 |  VACATION |          40 |
|     3 |  29 |      SICK |          44 |
|     3 |  21 | MATERNITY |          44 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbd1e3/16)** demo

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful insight! As I was incorrectly using DISTINCT with Max aggregate fnc.

Comment: You're very welcome. Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes it is! Its exactly what im looking for! Thank you @peterm

Comment: @Strawberry It's easy. It allows to grab the **correct** values of columns that are not used in `GROUP BY` clause (MySQL will take the values of the first row in the group), without join in back to the table after fetching max values. That's why a specific `ORDER BY` is used in inner select.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's an ugly hack! ;-)

Comment: Although MySQL gives no promises and officially this behavior is non-deterministic it works just fine. The problem is that a proper way in this particular case will be much slower, because you'll have to join back using a derived value (month).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT DAY( start_date ) AS d,
       MONTH( start_date ) AS mon, 
       sick_type,
       MAX( leave_count ) AS leave_count
FROM `company_attendance_tally`
GROUP BY mon, sick_type
```

Comment: This will give incorrect results (day won't correspond to max value) in the group.

Comment: Thanks peterm for your keen observation! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it 'by-the-book', consider the following...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM company_attendance_tally x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MONTH(start_date) start_month
            , sick_type
            , MAX(leave_count) max_leave_count
         FROM company_attendance_tally
        GROUP 
           BY MONTH(start_date)
            , sick_type
     ) y
    ON y.start_month = MONTH(x.start_date)
   AND y.sick_type = x.sick_type
   AND y.max_leave_count = x.leave_count;
```

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, ill look into this and benchmark the speed difference with using the native fcn as opposed to using the "hack" from peterm, its quite very interesting that we have learned alot by this realworld scenario! Hope this would help people in the future too